# Как получить PID процесса Python по имени файла на Windows?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Есть несколько запущенных скриптов на Python. Проблема в том, что любой запущенный скрипт либо через командную строку, либо через лаунчер называется одинаково. Нужно остановить один из них, при этом нельзя добавлять что либо другое в те скрипты.

Comment: Смотрите параметр запуска процесса

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример вывода команды `tasklist` для интересующих вас процессов и результат, который вы хотите получить. И что значит `при этом нельзя добавлять что либо другое в те скрипты` ??

Comment: @MaxU , **"при этом нельзя добавлять что либо другое в те скрипты"** - это значит, что ничего в скриптах менять нельзя, то есть решение должно быть универсально для всех процессов Python.
Я запустил несколько скриптов через лаунчер, при этом в tasklist все эти процессы называются "py.exe". Нужно понять, какой из скриптов процесс, для отлючения конкретного при надобности.

Comment: А создать какой-то внутренний процесс отключения скриптов не вариант? например при появлении файла `kill.txt` скрипт завершается?

Comment: @Kers , не вариант. Потому что должна быть возможность завершать любые процессы скриптов. Тем более одним из условий является то, что скрипты должны отключатся сторонним инструментом.

Comment: Думаю, что поставленная задача в общем виде нерешаема, потому что каждый скрипт может быть запущен более одного раза, таким образом, один файл может иметь множество соответствующих ему процессов.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev , отредактировал код. То как реализовал я - это именно то, что нужно для моей задачи. Я создал ftp сервер, на нем будет запущен скрипт-менеджер, который выполняет различные функции, одной из них является завершение процесса определенного скрипта. Делаю это для того, чтобы можно было удаленно управлять различными парсерами, ботами и т. д.

Comment: а сделать из этих скриптов ЕХЕшники с разными именами нельзя ? всёравноже нельзя их изменять.

Comment: @Интик , вообще не вариант. Я уже нашел решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так.

```
from os import path, system

file_path = path.abspath(__file__)[:-len(path.basename(__file__))]

buf_strings = []

system("wmic process get Caption, ProcessId, CommandLine >" + file_path + "PID.txt")

with open(file_path + "PID.txt", "r", encoding='utf-16-le') as file:
    for lines in file:
        if ".py" in lines and "python.exe" not in lines:
            for lines in lines.split():
                if "py.exe" not in lines:
                    buf_strings.append(lines)

print(buf_strings)
```

Comment: Можно точнее сформировать WMI-запрос. Например: wmic process where (commandline like '%.py%' and name='py.exe') get Caption, ProcessId, CommandLine